# How do I make Android continue playing the ringtone music instead of restarting it as peer calls again?

Tags: ringtone

Device receives a call, but there is no reply. In 3 minutes, there is another ring from the same peer.

How do I make long ringtone music continue from some point instead of starting from scratch when the phone is ringing soon enough?

Comment: I'm really not sure if this is possible (never heard of such feature). Also, is there a reason why you didn't pick up the call?

Comment: Because of I'm away from my phone and others around don't want to touch my device either to pick up a call or to just silence it. In case of when the call rings again and again, it is less annoying to hear continuation of ringtone music rather than the same 30 seconds again and again.

Comment: Aslo I just want in general to fine-tune how the phone rings and vibrates (which music/pattern depending on number, depending time of day, depending on history of calls and SMSes).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried doing this yet; but I believe you might be able to do it with this app called Automated Device, you can setup some rules to change the ringtone, and by cutting your song into chunks, and then using the flag functionality to define which rule is active at each moment, you could setup a rotation of ringtones that together play the full song.

Something like (pseudocode):

```
If phone is ringing, and the flag "ringtone step" is zero;
then change ringtone to cut 2 but only after 29 seconds, 
and set the flag "ringtone step" to 1.

If phone is ringing, and the flag "ringtone step" is 1;
then change ringtone to cut 3 but only after 29 seconds, 
and set the flag "ringtone step" to 2.

If phone is ringing, and the flag "ringtone step" is 2;
then change ringtone to cut 1 but only after 29 seconds,
and set the flag "ringtone step" to 0.
```

The 29 seconds thing is so it won't skip to the next chunk without completing the current one (if an action is delayed and the conditions stop being true, it won't execute). I'm not sure what happens if you try to change the ringtone while the phone is ringing though.

.

For doing anything complex with it, it is a bit like programming, but a lot more awkward. But simpler stuff is quite easy.

Perhaps there might be other apps; I haven't looked for an alternative in quite a while; this one is what I'm familiar with.

Comment: Is callers number and presense in phonebook and ringing history accessible to AutomatedDevice's conditionals? Continued ringtone should be only for immediate re-call of the same number.

Comment: The first one, yes. Regarding checking for numbers not on the contacts, I don't think that's possible with this app; but you can have rules for all the numbers you want to be treated differently from the rest, and then a rule that checks if the phone is ringing AND none of the rules with numbers defined are being triggered. As for call history, I don't think so; but you can add some flags to identify which rule was last executed, and use those flags as part of the conditions.